# WinAPI Toolbar Control: Increase Width of Drop Down Chevron

Tags: winapi, mfc, common-controls

Ist is possible to extend the width of the dropdown button for a Toolbarctrl button with BTNS_DROPDOWN style?

[image: this little boy here]

Reason: for this particular button, there is a default action (basically "use the same device as before") executed immediately, which is likely over 95% of all clicks. The dropdown allows to select another device to work with. 
Aiming for the chevron but clicking the default action instead by accident is a little dangerous however.

I want to avoid separate "use prev device" / "select other device" buttons, as this seems clumsy.

The actual control is an MFC CToolbar / CToolbarCtrl, I'm happy with a WinAPI or a MFC answer. (that's why the two tags) - but I assume there's little difference.

Comment: I don't think widening the the drop down button is going to fix your problem.  It should certainly lessen the chances of an incorrect click.  But, I'd suggest that the workflow design is at fault here.

Comment: No, you cannot increase this width without owner-drawing the entire thing. Which I don't recommend. Something is rather odd about your issue. Lots of applications use this type of control in their toolbars, and don't have any usability problems with it. Office used it for years, before they invented the Ribbon. It was used, for example, to Print or click the drop-down arrow to choose a different printer. If you clicked the wrong one, you got a printout on a printer you didn't want it to print on. Not catastrophic, but certainly frustrating. If yours is catastrophic, require a confirmation.